# Versioned File System like web interface

Tags: version-control, filesystems

I'm trying to find a free software that would provide a web interface to a file system (so you can add / remove files / directories, possibly edit them). If possible, it should handle versioning (only simple things needed : back to previous versions), and user management.

Can you point me to anything like that ? thanks

Update1 : I'm looking for a solution that would work on unix (e.g. linux).

Update2 : something like a subversion web interface on an Apache server would do the trick, alas I couldn't find any user friendly subversion web interface, Do you ? Plus it shold allow users to create new content.

Comment: Program-related, but not programming related.

Answer (score 1):

You want something that supports something called Web Distributed Authoring and Versioning (look up WebDAV).  Apple's MobileMe does this, as does Subversion over httpd, as does MS Sharepoint.

In fact, if you just want WebDAV functionality for free, try out Subversion and Apache.

Comment: Hi, indeed, I looked at various svn on http web interface, but they are all too complex to be used for a non-technocal user. Unless there is one svn web interface that is very user friendly ?

Comment: The interface is dead easy to use, you just attach your svn repository as a network drive.  It may be tricky for you to set it up as an administrator if you don't know what you're doing.  But it is very well documented.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [DropBox](http://www.getdropbox.com/)? It's a hosted solution (2GB for free). It has a web interface that allows you to do rollbacks/etc.

Comment: I use DropBox for my personal use and it rocks indeed. But I can't use that for professional use, I'd like to get the control of running it. But basically yes, a Dropbox like interface